# Redshift SQL: add and reset a counter with date and group considered

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, counter, window-functions, lag

Suppose I have a table below. I'd like to have a counter to count the # of times when a Customer (there are many) is in Segment A. If the Customer jumps to a different Segment between 2 quarters, the counter will reset when the Customer jumps back to Segment A. I am sure there are many ways to do it, but I just can't figure this out..Please help. Thank you!

```
Quarter    Segment    Customer    *Counter*
Q1 2018    A          A1          1
Q2 2018    A          A1          2
Q3 2018    A          A1          3
Q4 2018    B          A1          1
Q1 2019    B          A1          2
Q2 2019    A          A1          1
Q1 2020    A          A1          *1* I want 1 not 2 here because it's not consecutive
```

Comment: You can use `rank() Window Function` by partitioning over Quarter,Segment and Customer column and assign rank. Read more at -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_RANK.html
Example at -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_rank_WF.html

Comment: Why is B's counter 1,2 ,, shouldn't it be 1,1 because of diff years

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is, if I partition by these 3 columns, I would get 1 in all rows , right? If I only partition by Segment and order by Quarter, I would get 1-5 for Segment A and 1-2 for Segment B. How would I be able to take into account the break in Q4 2018 and Q1 2019, and restart the counter in Q2 2019?

Comment: @Fact The year doesn't matter here, as long as the value in the Segment in the previous quarter is the same in the current quarter in that row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can solve this with a difference of row numbers.  The real problem is dealing with the quarters.  But string functions can handle that.

```
select quarter, customer, segment,
       row_number() over (partition by customer, segment, seqnum - seqnum_cs order by right(quarter, 4), left(quarter, 2)) as counter
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer order by right(quarter, 4), left(quarter, 2)) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by customer, segment order by right(quarter, 4), left(quarter, 2)) as seqnum_cs
      from t
     ) t
order by customer, seqnum;
```

The key idea here is that the difference of row numbers defines the adjacent rows for a customer with the same status.  It can be a bit hard to see why this is the case.  However, if you look at the results of the subquery, you will no doubt see and understand why this is works.

Comment: Nice, I oversimplified my answer then realized that quarters and years needed to be virtualized as markers for this to work.

Comment: @gordon linoff Thank you Gordon Linoff! This is exactly what I am looking for! Also learned the term "gaps-and-islands" !

Comment: @gordon linoff Hello Gordon, I have a follow up - what if we have some breaks in the quarter? I modified the table in my question: Customer A1 is not in any segment in Q3 and Q4 2019, and then is back in segment A in Q1 2020. Using the method here the counter will be 2, but in reality it should be 1 (because it's not consecutive). Do you know how this can be handled? Thanks!

Comment: @gordon linoff oh looks like I can add a new column using case statement to compare if the current quarter is one quarter after the previous quarter (using lag window function) and if not true then force it to 1 else use the counter. And then I use this new column to rank to check if it's consecutive or not. Also if the previous_quarter is null (because it's the first occurrence) then also just use the old counter value. Looks like it's working

Comment: @user12562215 . . . It is better to ask a *new* question.  Your original question here was already answered.

Comment: @GordonLinoff https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431244/sql-gaps-and-island-problem-date-not-consecutive-causing-rank-inaccurate I posted a new question.