# SQL: Gaps and Island Problem - Date not consecutive causing rank inaccurate

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

This is a follow up on [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402755/redshift-sql-add-and-reset-a-counter-with-date-and-group-considered/59403044?noredirect=1#comment105018674_59403044) I asked.

```
Quarter    Segment    Customer    *Counter*
   Q1 2018    A          A1          1
   Q2 2018    A          A1          2
   Q3 2018    A          A1          3
   Q4 2018    B          A1          1
   Q1 2019    B          A1          2
   Q2 2019    A          A1          1
   Q1 2020    A          A1          *1* I want 1 not 2 here because it's not consecutive (we don't have Q3 & Q4 2019)
   Q2 2020    A          A1          *2* I want 2 not 3 here because it reset in Q1 2020.
```

Below query works if the dates are consecutive. How would I adjust the query to get what I'm looking for? I tried adding a new column that is 1 row lag, and tried to check if the quarter value in the new column is essentially the true previous 1 quarter (if yes, use the counter, if not, use "1" to restart). But it doesn't reset the following records. Then I am not sure what to do.

```
select quarter, customer, segment,
       row_number() over (partition by customer, segment, seqnum - seqnum_cs order by right(quarter, 4), left(quarter, 2)) as counter
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer order by right(quarter, 4), left(quarter, 2)) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by customer, segment order by right(quarter, 4), left(quarter, 2)) as seqnum_cs
      from t
     ) t
order by customer, seqnum;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your data model!  In any case, this is solved by enumerating the quarters.

```
select quarter, customer, segment,
       row_number() over (partition by customer, segment, q_seqnum - seqnum_cs order by q_seqnum) as counter
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer, segment order by q_seqnum) as seqnum_cs
      from (select t.*,
                   cast(right(quarter, 4) as int) * 4 + cast(substring(quarter, 2, 1) as int) as q_seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
order by customer, q_seqnum;
```

Comment: This does work! But can you explain! In my real data, this is a valid scenario as this is a derived table (not actual table) and if a customer doesn't meet certain condition, it's not in any segment. Also, in my real data, the quarter is not string but Date. So if we treat quarter as date (so no real need to do substring, cast), can this still be done? @Gordon linoff

Comment: @user12562215 . . . This is just generating a sequential number for quarters (year times four plus the quarter).  Then, subtracting an increasing sequence results in a constant value -- for adjacent numbers.